# python argparse create groups distributions for same arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to create a script in which I have 4 input variables, which can have several combinations between them to generate an output. For example I have: U, nu, Dh, Re. which are related by an equation Re = U * D / nu. What I want is to create groups where the right side of the equation is mandatory and the left one calculated, depending on the data input.

Right now I have this code which is working but I don´t like the way that I found to do this making all the inputs optionals and handling its with if statements:

```
def get_Re (U, D, nu):
    return (U*D/nu)

def get_nu (U, D, Re):
    return (U*D/Re)

def get_U (D, Re, nu):
    return (Re*nu/D)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('-U',  type=float, help='Fluid Speed [m/s]')
    parser.add_argument('-nu', type=float, help='Fluid kinematic viscosity [m^2/s]')
    parser.add_argument('-Dh', type=float, help='Hydraulic diameter [m]')
    parser.add_argument('-Re', type=float, help="Reynold's number")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.U and args.Dh and args.nu:
        Re = get_Re(args.U, args.Dh, args.nu)
    elif args.Re:
        Re = args.Re

    if args.U and args.Dh and args.Re:
        nu = get_nu(args.U, args.Dh, args.Re)
    elif args.nu:
        nu = args.nu

    if args.Dh and args.Re and args.nu:
        U = get_U(args.Dh, args.Re, args.nu)
    elif args.U:
        U = args.U
```

Comment: So 3 out of the 4 need to be provided?

Comment: @gmds, yes only 3 of the 4,

Comment: that kind of testing is best done after parsing, as you do.  `argparse` doesn't provide any tools to help with this.

Comment: @hpaulj, thanks, so I will use it in this way